# In essence, is there any real distinction between Democritus' conventions and the materialist sensible world

Tags: history-of-philosophy, atomism

Democritus, the atomist offered what appears to be a strikingly similar description of the 'real' structure of the world in his philosophy as composed of indestructible 'atoms'.

Similarly his 'conventions' seem to be replicated in the materialist's 'sensible' world. Is this a reasonable comparison?

*"Democritus asserted that space, or the Void, had an equal right with reality, or Being, to be considered existent. He conceived of the Void as a vacuum, an infinite space in which moved an infinite number of atoms that made up Being (i.e., the physical world). These atoms are eternal and indivisible; absolutely small, so small that their size cannot be diminished (hence the name atomon, or “indivisible”); absolutely full and incompressible, as they are without pores and entirely fill the space they occupy; and homogeneous, differing only in shape, arrangement, position, and magnitude. But, while atoms thus differ in quantity, differences of quality are only apparent, owing to the impressions caused on the senses by different configurations and combinations of atoms. A thing is hot or cold, sweet or bitter, or hard or soft only by convention; the only things that exist in reality are atoms and the Void."* (Britannica Online) CMS

Comment: Well, Democritus was a materialist, mechanistic rather than dialectical, as Marx would add. Stoics were also materialists (arguably), but they had a very different conception of the sensible world, with pneuma instead of atoms in the void, not unlike modern quantum vacuum. Are you asking how modern forms of materialism are similar/different from ancient atomism?

Comment: I don't think Democritus had a notion of atoms obeying mathematical laws of motion, and the more qualitative description he gave of why they moved the way they do is different from the assumptions of classical statistical mechanics which deals with statistics of large nos. of interacting particles (and it's definitely different from quantum theory). The [SEP article on Democritus](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/democritus/) describes the atoms as "repelling one another when they collide or combining into clusters by means of tiny hooks and barbs on their surfaces, which become entangled".

Comment: As I understand it, the atomist's notion of *atom* satisfies the Parmenidean requirements for reality - i.e., not subject to "coming-to-be" or "passing-away" and otherwise unchangeable except for position, which does not alter their inner being.

Comment: @Nick - A change in position is a change. Democritus describes a world of multiplicity and change much like QM, viz. a collection of objects in a void. Parmenides had a very different idea. I would agree with the OP that Democritus describes the material world. His idea is not metaphysical and fails to explain anything.

Comment: @PeterJ Hi Peter, My (limited) understanding of the Presocratics comes from Patricia Curd's *A Presocratics Reader - Selected Fragments and Testimonia*.  In it she explicitly states that Democritus and the atomist's system is Parmenidean.  Perhaps the confusion is caused by the distinction between "ultimate reality" as unchanging in every respect, and the world of our senses where change is sensed.  The atomist void is literal void - i.e., "no thing" - while QM permits no such void but describes "empty space" as a seething field of virtual particles continuously popping in and out of existence

Comment: @Nick. Hi. I have no idea why Curd sees Democritus as Parmenidean. Plato wanted to burn the books of the former but not the latter. Afaik Parmenides asks us to go beyond space-time while Democritus makes it irreducible, Thus the former has a metaphysical theory, or the beginnings of one, while the latter has only a non-reductive physical theory (thus is sometimes considered the Father of Physics). Accordingly, Unity is an important issues for the pre-Socratics but not for Democritus. For the atomists the void is just space-time as it is. A metaphysical theory must reduce space-time and atoms.

Comment: @PeterJ That all makes sense.  I'll have another look at Curd's text when I can.  Right now I'm painting my new flat, so I have all my books piled up in a heap in one of the spare bedrooms upstairs.  When I have finished and get myself organised again I'll see what I can find.  It's most likely that I have misunderstood and that her claim is somehow qualified.

Comment: @PeterJ I have managed to locate Curd's text.  This is what she writes in her introduction to the chapter on Leucippus and Democritus: "*The atomists claim that there are an indefinite number of these atoms, each of which is uniform, not subject to coming-to-be or passing-away, and unchangeable in any other way, except position, an external change that does not affect their inner core of atomic being.  Atoms thus satisfy the Parmendidean requirements for reality.*"

Comment: At Nick- Sounds a lot like today's atomic theory. Why is it that the pre-Socratics get so little credit for advanced thinking?

Comment: @CharlesMSaunders I'm not sure that is entirely true.  Most physicists aren't really interested in philosophy, however those at the top of their game tend to be familiar with philosophy.  Carlo Rovelli, one of the leading figures in Loop Quantum Gravity wrote an entire [book on Anaximander](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/12632657-the-first-scientist).

Comment: @Nick - Interesting. I feel Curd is quite wrong. Atoms do not meet the Parmenidean  requirements, I can see no difference between the idea that a multiplicity of atoms are fundamental and naive Realism. +1 for Carlo Rovelli. .

Comment: @Nick- Just bought the book, great referral, thanks. Just one point, I did not mean to say that physicists cared about or read philosophy just that the Pre-Socratics deserve more credit for their scientific acumen. CMS